# Reactive<UISegmentedControl> in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I am trying to add remove cells from a `UITableView` depending on the value changes in a `UISegmentedControl` which is inside one of `UITableViewCell`.

The problem is there is a cyclic dependency and the tableView keeps reloading. I avoided this infinite reload by using `distinctUntilChanged` but still sometimes the reload is called twice.

My objective is to change the number of rows depending on the selection made in the segment control.

> Code in UITableViewCell

---

```
extension CardTableViewCell {

    /// This function is called every time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the tableView.

    func bind(viewModel: TableViewViewModel?) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        if let viewModel = viewModel {
            segment.rx.selectedSegmentIndex
                .asDriver()
                .flatMap { Driver.just($0 == 0)}
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .drive(onNext: { value in

                    print(">>>> VALUE CHANGED \(value)")
                    viewModel.reloadTableView()}

                // Here when I reload the table view this is called again and a cyclic dependency is created

                ) >>> disposeBag
        }
    }
}
```

> The console returns this

```
⚠️ Reentrancy anomaly was detected.
  > Debugging: To debug this issue you can set a breakpoint in /Users/harshvishwakarma/Documents/GitHub/banking-app-ios/Pods/RxSwift/RxSwift/Rx.swift:97 and observe the call stack.
  > Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
    This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
    Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.
  > Interpretation: This could mean that there is some kind of unexpected cyclic dependency in your code,
    or that the system is not behaving in the expected way.
  > Remedy: If this is the expected behavior this message can be suppressed by adding `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)`
    or by enqueing sequence events in some other way.
```

Comment: try to use Single instead of Observable

Comment: The single doesn't work. Using that I have to be more careful as it only emits once.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a library like `[RxDataSources][1]` or otherwise write your own data source class. The behavior of the default data source is to call `reloadData()` on the table view, but you need one that will append/delete cells on demand instead of always loading the entire tableView.

If you feel that RxDataSources is too heavy weight, then you can write a simple data source of your own. Here's an example: https://github.com/danielt1263/RxMultiCounter/blob/master/RxMultiCounter/RxExtensions/RxSimpleAnimatableDataSource.swift

Comment: The `reloadTableView` is just a place holder in this code here. I am actually adding/removing the cells but the problem was same many cells have checkboxes or segments which all trigger an event when the cell is created. I have already found a solution using `Signal` instead of `Driver`. I'll post it soon after I've tested it.